# How can I execute shortcode outside the loop?

Tags: shortcode

I'm using Contact Form 7 and can display the form by putting the following in the content text field `[contact-form-7 id="453" title="Contact form 1"]`.

Now I need to display the form outside the loop.

How can I execute a short code from within my template code?

**Update**
I found some suggestions to execute shortcode outside the loop:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="453" title="Contact form 1"]') ?>
```

This solution works fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[do_shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) should do the trick. I don't think you need the 'echo' before it though, I have never done so myself and never had any problems.

Comment: Yes it did. I just had butterfingers when implementing it. It works now :)

Comment: @Steven, glad I Could help :3

Comment: I know it's a very old question but did you manage to use this with `on_sent_ok:  "$(".form-div").fadeOut();"` somehow this doesn'r work outside the loop, but i does send the form

Answer (score 1):

1. Dig into the `Contact Form 7` plugin;
2. Find occurrence of `add_shortcode( 'contact-form-7', 'some_contact_form_function' )` function;
3. Learn `some_contact_form_function` function parameters;
4. Call it from your code.

Comment: I know I can dig into the code. But I know I have seen somewhere that shortcode can be executed outside the loop. I just don't remember how. And it's a lot easier than digging around somebody elses' code.

Comment: All you need is to find `add_shortcode( 'contact-form-7', ... )` or `add_filter( 'the_content', '...' )` calls. If you find it, you will see which function is called to process this shortcode. If you know which function processes it, you can call it directly whenever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add this to help people like me who was trying to figure out how to end or close the shortcode...

The answer is here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

For example:

```
// In case there is opening and closing shortcode
echo do_shortcode('[iscorrect]'.$text_to_be_wrapped_in_shortcode.'[/iscorrect]');
```